# How to multiprocess multiple excel sheets using pandas read_excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, multiprocess

I'm in need of a helping hand.

I've the problem that i can't access the *RETURN* of my function calls while using the multiprocessing modul in python-3.x. 
If using the threading modul would be better idea i would accept this as well.

```
import multiprocessing
from pandas import read_excel

path1 = r"C:\ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO\excelfile.xls"
sheets = ["sheet_1", "sheet_2", "sheet_3"]
procs = []

def read_xls(path, sheet):
    df = read_excel(path, sheet_name=sheet, header=0, decimal=',', delim_whitespace=True)
    return df


for index, sheet in enumerate(sheets) :
    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=read_xls, args=(path1, sheet))
    procs.append(proc)
    proc.start()

for proc in procs:
    proc.join()
```

Further, i wanna use that code as a class and don't wanna run it as main file:

```
if __init__ == '__main__':
    class()
```

How can i get a list or dict of my dataframes returned? 
Can i run it as multiprocess class later in an other main programm? 
For example: I wanna run this class later in the background of a Kivy GUI while pressing a load button.

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: I adepted my code to this [source](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2016/08/02/python-201-a-multiprocessing-tutorial/)

**EDIT**:
The reason i wanna access the sheets with 3 parallel processes or threads is to accelerate the loading time.

Comment: Check here https://pbpython.com/pandas-excel-tabs.html

Comment: You could use the `map` method from `multiprocessing.Pool` instead, but if all you are doing is reading the sheets into dataframes, there isn't any advantage to multiple processes (it will likely be slower because the sheet needs to be passed to the parent processs) or threads (you are mostly blocking on the reads).

Comment: Thank you for informing about the performance loss.

Answer (score 2):

You can read all the sheets from an excel file at once, then access them separately.

```
all_sheets = read_excel(path, sheet_name=None, header=0, decimal=',', delim_whitespace=True)

sheet_1 = all_sheets['sheet_1']
sheet_2 = all_sheets['sheet_2']
sheet_3 = all_sheets['sheet_3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the goal of this attempt was to load faster the excel sheets, but it seems this is not feasible due to the answer of "tdelany".

Post can be closed-